# Ground a student survey in academic literature

Tags: reference-request, methodology, experimental-psychology, educational-psychology, survey

I'm planning to do a survey with students (age around 16) with questions/answer-possibilities that have been 'proven' to be significant indicators of student success/good grades. So, I'm not really interested in the relationship of the variables to the outcome, instead, I want to feed the data of the survey to a machine learning algorithm to check the algorithm's correctness.

Instead of coming up with the questions of the survey myself, I would like to ground them academically, i.e.: based on academic literature. I don't need very 'original' ones, the significance of the variables themselves is not the focus of my research (actually, I want 'proven' significant variables).

Best case scenario would be to find a canonical list of survey questions and answer-possibilities which have been 'proven' to be influential (significant) indicators of student success/grades, from which I can take the ones appropriate for my research.

Another thing that would be help me is a source which discusses good and bad practices for setting up a survey such as mine (which might also point me to the questions I want to ask).

I have found some papers, such as (Sykes & Kuyper, 2009) about predicting student success/grades, from which I can pick some variables/questions, but none of them were close enough to my case to be fully satisfactory for my purpose. If anyone can help me with a good paper that investigates roughly the same as my research, this would also help, as I might then base my survey (partly) on this research.

Comment: Adding some links to the papers you have read would be helpful. (:

Comment: Some types of IQ tests are commonly used to predict academic achievement with some success - is this the sort of thing you had in mind?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm more looking for 'simple' features like motivation (what kind of questions would measure this in a good way for example?) and personalia (which have been 'known' to influence performance?). I'm aiming for a relatively simple survey, purely to get some data on the features to feed to the ML algorithm. An IQ test for example, is too complicated for my purpose. I want to do the survey in approx. 15 mins.

Answer (score 1):

Both [Carol Dweck](https://psychology.stanford.edu/cdweck) and [Angela Duckworth](https://sites.sas.upenn.edu/duckworth/pages/research) have fairly brief tests meant to measure student success and by some extension grades.

Dweck's work focuses on how having a "fixed mindset" limits a students ability to grow in a subject and is used to explain why students are so apt to give up when met with challenge. Her [quiz](http://mindsetonline.com/testyourmindset/step1.php) would have to be formatted for pen and paper and her research is rather sparse on the subject.

Duckworth focuses on both grit and self-control. She has researched heavily the effects of grit over the last 10 years while Walter Mischel works on self-control and has been for the past 40 years. Duckworth was Mischels student. Unfortunately, his test for self-control would likely be too abstract for your needs.

Needless to say her work has been shown to measure student success over the last ten years. Her [website offers several quizzes](https://sites.sas.upenn.edu/duckworth/pages/research) on grit or self control for adults and students. The same links provides access to her publications.